# How to get variable attribute in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I return a specific attribute of a variable using d3?

For example, I want to select an element by mouseover, and pass on the selection to a function, but only if the element's `id` is a particular name.

Something like this?

```
d3.select("body").on("mouseover", function(){ 
    if (d3.select(this).attr("id") == "correct") {
        enableInteraction(d3.select(this));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. Select `this` and then use the usual functions to access properties.

Comment: What are the usual functions to access (not set) the properties?

Comment: `.attr("something")`, like you said.

Comment: If you want any style property of the element then `.style("something")`