# changing color of d3.js pie chart label when hovering over slice?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover

I'm currently changing the color of the slice directly on hover using css, but I'd like to affect the color of the label instead. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this using the d3 syntax, any tips would be appreciated.
Thanks!

```
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
  .data(pie)
  .enter()
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "slice")
  ;

arcs.append("svg:path")
  .attr("fill", function(d){
    console.log(d.data.label, " ", (d.endAngle - d.startAngle))
    if(d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .24){
        return "#00C189"
    } else {
        return "#E3594B"
    }
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .on('click', function(d){ getRSS(d.data.label); })
  .on('mouseover', function(d) { 
     // CHANGE LABEL COLOR HERE
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d){
    // CHANGE LABEL COLOR BACK HERE
});

arcs.filter(function(d) { return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2; }).append("svg:text")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
    d.outerRadius = outerRadius; // Set Outer Coordinate
    d.innerRadius = outerRadius*.3; // Set Inner Coordinate
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";
    })
  .style("fill", "White")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.label; })
  ;
```

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309147/how-to-get-variable-attribute-in-d3) helps

Comment: I think that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387898/how-to-assign-unique-id-to-svg-text-element-in-d3-javascript) might help you more

Comment: so you think that applying unique id to each label and interacting with them that way is the most direct?
doesn't seem too bad. thanks for the link

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
arcs.on("mouseover", function() {
  d3.select(this)
    .select("text")
    .style("fill", "green");
}).on("mouseout", function() {
  d3.select(this)
    .select("text")
    .style("fill", "black");
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var width = 960,
  height = 500,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);

var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 40)
  .innerRadius(radius - 40);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.population;
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var data = [{
  "age": "<5",
  "population": 2704659
}, {
  "age": "5-13",
  "population": 4499890
}, {
  "age": "14-17",
  "population": 2159981
}, {
  "age": "18-24",
  "population": 3853788
}, {
  "age": "25-44",
  "population": 14106543
}, {
  "age": "45-64",
  "population": 8819342
}, {
  "age": "≥65",
  "population": 612463
}];

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.age);
  });

g.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.age;
  });

g.on("mouseover", function() {
  d3.select(this)
    .select("text")
    .style("fill", "green");
}).on("mouseout", function() {
  d3.select(this)
    .select("text")
    .style("fill", "black");
});

function type(d) {
  d.population = +d.population;
  return d;
}
```

```css
.arc text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that worked great! I didn't realize you could select the child elements so easily.

thanks a bunch!